# How to avoid records duplication while bulk/single insertion of records on single click asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am saving records using single click in asp.net web forms and after single click button got disabled but still it is inserting duplicate or multiple records in database for random users. Duplication is random and there is no pattern for duplication i.e., among 80,000 entered 3000, 4000 rows are duplicated. What could be the exact issue, is it server side or client side and how to workaround this issue without using "not exists" in query ? Thanks in advance.

I am using Sql Server 2012.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43093/Submit-Once-with-an-ASP-NET-Button-Server-Control

Comment: @HenrykBudzinski I have already implemented this in my code but issue is there. How to put is exist check in stored procedure getting values from user defined table and then saving it into database as bulk table.

Comment: change the title to "How to avoid records duplication while bulk/single insertion of records in a stored procedure"